# Number of real solutions of equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The number of real solutions to the equation:

$$\sqrt{3x^2 - 18x + 52} + \sqrt{2x^2 - 12x + 162}  =\sqrt{-x^2 +  6x + 280}$$

Please suggest a shorter method than just squaring both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requested shorter method:

Show that the left hand side is always bigger than $18$ while the right hand side ( when defined) is always less than $18.$

Comment: Indeed, but how did you discover that ? You are not telling the whole story.

Comment: The was probably a silent change in the OP, as this is wrong. Shouldn't be the accepted answer !

Comment: @YvesDaoust  the second answer appeared about the same time mine did. I did want to ask at the time whether (he?) had seen the same source and knew there was a typo in this question, or was judging on grounds of elegance. Meanwhile, I just graphed the original curves.

Comment: Ok, let's assume that plotting is allowed and considered short. But what do you do after observing the upper/lower bound graphically ? You should confirm analytically.

Answer (score 1):

By pulling the quadratic coefficients from the square roots,

$$\sqrt3\sqrt{x^2 - 6x + \frac{52}3} + \sqrt2\sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 81} = \sqrt{-x^2 +  6x + 280}$$

you observe that all expressions under the square roots have a single extremum at $x=3$.

At that point, the LHS equals

$$\sqrt{27-54+52}+\sqrt{18-36+162}=5+12=17$$

and the RHS

$$\sqrt{-9+18+280}=17.$$

As

$$LHS\ge17\ge RHS$$ there is a single solution $x=3$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a typo in the first square root: $3x^2-18x+52$ should be the correct version. In that case: $$17 = 5+12\leq\sqrt{3(x-3)^2+5^2} + \sqrt{2(x-3)^2+12^2} = \sqrt{17^2-(x-3)^2}\leq 17,$$

so $x=3$. In the original version, the left side hand side is strictly greater than $17$, so there is no solution.